# Sed command matching pattern UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I want to delete  lines from the file using sed command in linux but problem is that 
if , I want to match "abcd" it matches "abcd.efgh" also . I just want to match not "abcd.efgh"
. I have searched on google but didnt find any solution .

Comment: You need to be much more precise. What do the lines look like in the two cases? You might just need a '$'.

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/abcd/ && !/abcd\.efgh/' file
```

It will match lines that are `abcd` but not `abcd.efgh`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is simply what you want:

```
sed -i '/^abcd$/d' file
```

It would only delete lines that give an exact match of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/\babcd\b/)' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GUN sed):

```
sed '/abcd\.efgh/b;/abcd/d' file
```

or to put another way:

```
sed '/abcd/{/abcd\.efgh/!d}' file
```